# 2D array to draw a letter 'F'

Tags: java, array, homework, ascii-art

This is my code to print letter 'F' with nested loop 2d array. Are there changes that could be made in it to make it look better or more efficient?

```
 for (int i=0;i<=4;i++){


        for(int j=0;j<=4;j++){

            array[i][j]='*';
            if ( array[1][1]=='*' || array[1][2]=='*' || array[1][3]=='*' || array[1][4]== '*'||
                 array[3][1]=='*' || array[3][2]=='*' || array[3][3]=='*' || array[3][4]== '*' 
               ||array[4][1]=='*' || array[4][2]=='*' || array[4][3]=='*' || array[4][4]== '*')
                {
                array[i][j]=' ';
            }
          }
        }
        for (int i=0;i<=4;i++){
          for(int j=0;j<=4;j++){
            System.out.print(" "+array[i][j]);
        }
            System.out.println("\n");
       }
```

Comment: It looks like this code should be preceded by `char[][] array = new char[5][5];`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One glaring issue about your code is that you are taking the requirement of 'nested 2D array' ***too literally*** by simply hard-coding the positions of your 2D array you want to 'erase', as indicated by that lengthy `if`-statement.

If you re-think your original assignment in another way, consider how the letter `F` is written:

```
*****
*
*****
*
*
```

1. Loop fully with all `*`.
2. Print only a single `*`.
3. Loop fully with all `*`, again.
4. Print only a single `*`, again.
5. Print only a single `*`, again.

Thus, the looping that I believe is required of your assignment is to handle the number of times you need to print horizontally across per line, up to the number of lines required. Instead of 1 lengthy `if`-statement that decides what to erase, I foresee a couple of smaller, easier-to-understand `if` statements that control *when* to output a `*`.

Once you have your loops that can reproduce the multi-line `String` in [@200_success](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/104406/27975)'s answer, you can use the `Print with 2x magnification` trick to get your desired output as well.

Answer (score 4):

I can't imagine any good reason for drawing an F using that approach.  Drawbacks include:

- It is not obvious at all, just from looking at the code, what the expected output is.
- Not only is the code hard to read, it is also hard to write and modify.
- Using many small `System.out.print()` calls is very inefficient.

A solution like this, for example, is much easier to understand.  It would also be more efficient, since all of the output is done in one `System.out.print()` call.

```
public static final String F =
    "*****\n" +
    "*    \n" +
    "*****\n" +
    "*    \n" +
    "*    \n";

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // Print with 2x magnification
    System.out.print(F.replace("*", " *").replace("\n", "\n\n"));
}
```

Comment: One problem I spot with this is, that it's pretty much impossible to draw more than one character in a line. I would suggest actually storing the data line-wise, then you can iterate through a list a characters and draw their first lines, then their second lines, etc.

Comment: yes m getting your point but i have given this task from my teacher to do this nested loop and 2d array.